In Android 15 can a Device Admin App start a service from the background
With the recent changes in Android 15 where there are even more restrictions on starting services from the background I have not seen if device admin apps are part of this restriction.
Before I would hold the SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission which allowed me to start a service but now you need a window visible to be able to start.
I have a admin app that needs to start a few services, some are from other apps and they need to run from time to time when in the background. Can the admin app still launch those?

Is it required for you to run those services in Background, or can you run them in as a foreground service?
Running as foreground service it will display a persistent notification while running, but you shouldn't have issues to do it.

foreground service is fine they just need to be started while the app may be in the background which the docs say you cant do anymore
